# Websocket implementation of Tomcat 8.0.33 doesn't throw an IOException immediately when sendText() method is called(server side)

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat8

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0.33.
I was going through Java documentation about RemoteEndpoint.Basic
which says that **sendText(String text) blocks until all of the message
has been transmitted.**
But I noticed that when the client loses internet connection and
sendText() method is called on the server side, it doesn't thrown an
IOException immediately and the method returns normally.
IOException is thrown later and the onError() method is called.
Is
this a normal behaviour? **Shouldn't the sendText() method block until
all the message has been transmitted successfully or throw an
IOException immediately if there's any problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is normal.

Depending on how the client disconnects, there server might not know and the message will sit in the network buffer until the network stack figures out that
the client has gone away.

Comment: I noticed that IOException is thrown and onError() is called much later. So is there any way we can find out which sendText() caused the exception as the code could contain thousands of sendText() calls?

Comment: No. If you need per message acknowledgement you'll need to implement that yourself.